# I can't run boot0.s file using gcc command

Tags: gcc, assembly, ubuntu-18.04

I'm a total newbie in Ubuntu & Assembly Language. Recently one of the lab tasks asks me to compile `.s` file in Ubuntu to see what the output shows & explain them later. My teacher has also provided me some commands to compile and object linking with `boot0.S` file. But whenever I try to run this following command, I get several errors.

**Building boot0: Compilation**

```
$ gcc ‐MD ‐fno‐builtin ‐nostdinc ‐fno‐stack‐protector ‐Os ‐g ‐m32 ‐I. ‐c ‐o boot0.o boot0.S
```

It's giving me errors like these:

> gazzali@ubuntu:~/OS Lab Task/OS-challenging-IUTCSE16/Project 0/boot/boot0$ gcc ‐MD ‐fno‐builtin ‐nostdinc ‐fno‐stack‐protector ‐Os ‐g ‐m32 ‐I. ‐c ‐o boot0.o boot0.S
>
> gcc: error: ‐MD: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐fno‐builtin: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐nostdinc: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐fno‐stack‐protector: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐Os: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐g: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐m32: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐I.: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐c: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: ‐o: No such file or directory
>
> gcc: error: boot0.o: No such file or directory

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VMWare on Windows 10. I will also provide `boot0.S` file if needed. Can you please help to find a way to run this assembly file? There are more 2 assembly files which I need to run via similar commands.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does `gcc -v` report? Also `type gcc`?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe `gcc -v` returns a long sequence like : ` Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc ...  Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 
`  and `type gcc` returns `gcc is hashed (/usr/bin/gcc)`

Comment: Make sure you have a normal `-` character not some unicode stuff. `gcc` will not recognize that and will try to treat it as filename.

Comment: @Jester I don't understand it. Yes, I'm copying that gcc command from a PDF file. Is that causing an error?

Comment: Sounds like it, yes. Just delete all the `-` characters from the command line and retype them by hand.

Comment: @Jester , Yes. Now It works. Thanks a Lot :) . Didn't know about that actually

Comment: Maybe raise this with your teacher? See if they can avoid using em dash and en dash when creating the PDF. It's likely down to the word processor they used, however.